# Having trouble considering a finite field $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields

As the title states, I'm having trouble considering a finite field $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ as a vector space V over $\mathbb{F}_p$. Clearly it is dimension $n$. How can we work with this vector space? Specifically, I am trying to find the the characteristic polynomial of $\sigma_p : x \rightarrow x^p$ and deduce some things about it, but I'm not sure how to grasp it.

So I don't even know how to think about the bases. If $\mathbb{F}_p = \{a_1, a_2, ... a_p\},$ then is $\mathbb{F}_{p^n} = \{a_1, a_1^2, ... a_1^n, a_2, a_2^2, .... a_p^n\}$?

Anything helps, thanks.

CK

Comment: ${\mathbb F_{p^n}}$ or ${\mathbb F}_p^n$?

Comment: Is is ${\mathbb F}_p^n$ (i.e. the product of $n$ copies of ${\mathbb F}_p$), or is it ${\mathbb F}_{p^n}$ (the finite field of order $p^n$)?  These are not quite the same.

Comment: Yup...the above confusion both Magdi and R. Israel mention happened to me: I thought it was $\;\Bbb F_p^n\;$ though it seems to be it is $\;\Bbb F_{p^n}\;$ ...of course, both vector spaces over $\;\Bbb F_p\;$ are isomorphic, yet one *also* has the structure of a field...I shall delete my first comment.

Comment: $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$, sorry was just careless in proofreading.

Comment: You don't know what $\Bbb F_{p^n}$ is? The set $\{a_1,a_2^2,\cdots,a_p^n\}$ is equal to the set $\{a_1,\cdots,a_p\}$ which is just $\Bbb F_p$, not $\Bbb F_{p^n}$.

Comment: So each element of $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ can be represented as a $n \times n$ matrix with entries modulo $p$?

Comment: The field $\mathbf{F}_{p^n}$ must contain something not in $\mathbf{F}_p.$  If $a_j\in\mathbf{F}_p,$ then any power of $a_j$ is also in $\mathbf{F}_p.$  To get $\mathbf{F}_{p^n},$ you have to adjoin to $\mathbf{F}_p$ a root of an irreducible polynomial of degree $n.$  If $\alpha$ is such a root, then elements of $\mathbf{F}_{p^n}$ are quantities like $c_0+c_1\alpha+c_2\alpha^2+\ldots+c_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1},$ where the coefficients $c_j$ are elements of $\mathbf{F}_p.$  You can see that such quantities behave like vectors under addition and multiplication by an element of $\mathbf{F}_p.$

Comment: @WillOrrick Ahh so then the Frobenius $\sigma_p: c_0+c_1\alpha+c_2\alpha^2+\ldots+c_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1} \rightarrow (c_0+c_1\alpha+c_2\alpha^2+\ldots+c_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1})^p = c_0^p+c_1^p\alpha^p+c_2^p\alpha^{2p}+\ldots+c_{n-1}^p\alpha^{p(n-1)}$, correct?

Comment: That looks right.

Comment: @WillOrrick Okay. Now I need the LT $\sigma_p$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{F}_p \iff n|(p-1)$ and diagonalizable over $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p} \iff (n,p) = 1.$ So the linear transformation $\sigma_p$ is diagonalizable if the characteristic polynomial is a product of distinct linear factor, i.e. $n$ distinct eigenvalues over $\mathbb{F}_p$. I don't know where to go from here..

Comment: The multiplicative group $\Bbb{F}_p^*$ is cyclic of order $p-1$ and thus has all the $n$th roots of unity for any $n\mid(p-1)$. It is a basic fact about finite fields that $\sigma_p^n$ is the identity mapping on $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$. Can you put these together?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

The elements of $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ are the roots of $$f(x) = x^{p^n} -x \in \mathbb{F}_{p}[x]$$ To understand this recall that the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ is cyclic of order $p^n -1$.

This implies that $$\sigma_{p}^{n} = 1$$ and so the characteristic polynomial of $\sigma_p$ is $x^n -1 $

For the second point: $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ of dimension $n$ so if $\lbrace v_1 \ldots v_n \rbrace$ is a basis $$\mathbb{F}_{p^n} = \lbrace \sum_{j = 1}^{n} r_{j}v_j | \ \ r_j \in \mathbb{F_p}\rbrace$$

The set you wrote is not correct, for example because it contains $np$ elements and not $p^n$